# Win api: HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE

Tags: c++, windows, heap-memory

if I have a heap that was created as

```
HANDLE handle = HeapCreate(0,0,0);
```

and if I know that all `HeapAlloc` calls happen from only a single thread, however, `HeapFree` may be called from multiple threads - is it okay then to allocate memory using `HeapAlloc(heap_handle_, HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, bytes);` so long as the `HeapFree` calls do not specify `HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE`, or will that corrupt the heap?

Comment: _"... There is a small performance cost to serialization, but it must be used whenever multiple threads allocate and __free__ memory from the same heap...."_ source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc

Comment: No, it's not OK. From `HeapAlloc` documentation: "Without serialization, two or more threads that use the same heap handle might attempt to **allocate or free** memory simultaneously, likely causing corruption in the heap." Emphasis mine. The program should not allow the possibility that alloc an free happen in parallel.

Comment: Also from the HeapAlloc documentation: "The HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE value can, therefore, be safely used only in the following situations:" It then lists the three situations where it can be used. Yours does not match any of them.